# JXDatePicker using SimpleDateFormat to format dd.MM.yy to dd.MM.yyyy with current century

Tags: java, regex, swing, simpledateformat, swingx

as already explained I want to achieve, that when the user is editing a date within a JXDatePicker, he can choose, weather he types it again in the same format, which is by default dd.MM.yyyy or just dd.MM.yy. When he uses the short form I want the Picker to choose the current century.

**Example:**

```
27.01.2012 edited to 27.01.10 should result in 27.01.2010
```

as well as:

```
27.01.2012 edited to 27.01.2010 should also result in 27.01.2010
```

By default the JXDatePicker handels it the following way:

```
27.01.2012 edited to 27.01.10 results in 27.01.0010
```

Which is not really the way I wanted it to work. After some short research I found the following Method in SimpleDateFormat

```
/**
 * Sets the 100-year period 2-digit years will be interpreted as being in
 * to begin on the date the user specifies.
 *
 * @param startDate During parsing, two digit years will be placed in the range
 * <code>startDate</code> to <code>startDate + 100 years</code>.
 */
public void set2DigitYearStart(Date startDate)
```

On first view this sounded exactly like what I need. So I tested it and unfortunatly it didnt work like I hoped it would. This is because I want to use dd.MM.yyyy as format to display dates and also want it to be displayed like that in editmode. For example when the user klicks on a date like 27.01.2012, I also want it to be like that in editmode, too and not just the short form: 27.01.12.

My Problem now is, that set2DigitYearStart(Date) unfortunatly only works, when I choose to use the shortform in editmode. I made a small example to show this case (SwingX Library is required, because of jxdatepicker and can be found be [here](http://swinglabs.org/downloads.jsp)).

```
public class DatePickerExample extends JPanel
{
  static JFrame frame;

  public DatePickerExample()
  {
    JXDatePicker picker = new JXDatePicker();
    JTextField field = new JTextField( 10 );

    add( field );
    add( picker );

    final Calendar instance = Calendar.getInstance();
    instance.set( 2012, 01, 26 );
    Date date = instance.getTime();
    picker.setDate( date );

    //    SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat( "dd.MM.yy" );//Works, but I wonna display and edit it with dd.MM.yyyy
    SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat( "dd.MM.yyyy" );
    final Date startDate = new Date( 0 );//01.01.1970
    format.set2DigitYearStart( startDate );

    picker.setFormats( format );
  }

  public static void main( String[] args )
  {
    frame = new JFrame();
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation( JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE );
    frame.setBounds( 400, 400, 400, 400 );
    frame.setLayout( new BorderLayout() );
    frame.add( new DatePickerExample() );
    frame.setVisible( true );
  }
}
```

Anyone already had the same requirement and can tell me how to make this work? Any ideas are welcome. Thank you very much in advance. ymene

Comment: *"I want the Picker to choose the current century."*  Ah, preparing for the Y2.1K bug early, I see.  ;)

Comment: Haha, got me! Eventhough its 2012, there is nothing wrong with considering how the software would work in future! :P

Answer (score 5):

**Final** (hopefully :)

Summary of the first edit:

- DatePickerFormatter already implements a lookup strategy (or CompoundFormat, as suggested by @Robin)
- the lookup sequence for parsing is configurable by client code
- the idea is to try parsing starting with the first (typically the "longest"), if that fails try the next (typically "not-so-long") and so on until succeeded or a parseException is thrown
- for year parsing, SimpleDateFormat has rules that conflict with that longest-first lookup: it requires that "yy" is tried before "yyyy"
- doing so in datePicker has the unwanted side-effect of always showing the date with the short year format

The reason is DatePickerFormatter: it doesn't allow to specify the *formatting* format (simply uses the first). The way out is a custom DatePickerFormatter, which supports it (in the snippet, it's hardcoded to use the second):

```
SimpleDateFormat longFormat = new SimpleDateFormat( "dd.MM.yyyy" );
SimpleDateFormat shortFormat = new SimpleDateFormat( "dd.MM.yy" );
Date startDate = new Date( 0 );//01.01.1970
shortFormat.set2DigitYearStart( startDate );

DatePickerFormatter formatter = new DatePickerFormatter(
// invers sequence for parsing to satisfy the year parsing rules
        new DateFormat[] {shortFormat, longFormat}) {

            @Override
            public String valueToString(Object value) throws ParseException {
                if (value == null) return null;
                return getFormats()[1].format(value);
            }
        } ;
DefaultFormatterFactory factory = new DefaultFormatterFactory(formatter );
picker.getEditor().setFormatterFactory(factory);
```

Not entirely sure if we should support configuring the formatter in the base class. The DatePickerFormatter is a bit strange beast, not extending InternalFormatter and with the lookup process being a bit in competition with a FormatterFactory...

**Original**

It's not exactly the datePicker which handles it that way, it's the core formatting (as D1e already noted). None of the default format/ter/s support two formats at the same time: to see, try to achieve your goal with a core JFormattedTextField :-)

The way out might be a FormatterFactory: it allows to use different formats, depending on context: display and edit - the latter is used when the field is focused, the former at all other times.  As the picker's editor *is* a JFormattedTextField, you can configure it directly (instead of using the setFormats methods)

```
    SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat( "dd.MM.yyyy" );
    SimpleDateFormat editFormat = new SimpleDateFormat( "dd.MM.yy" );

    final Date startDate = new Date( 0 );//01.01.1970
    instance.setTime(startDate);
    editFormat.set2DigitYearStart( instance.getTime() );
    DefaultFormatterFactory factory = new DefaultFormatterFactory(
            new DatePickerFormatter(new DateFormat[] {format}),
            new DatePickerFormatter(new DateFormat[] {format}),
            new DatePickerFormatter(new DateFormat[] {editFormat})
            );
    picker.getEditor().setFormatterFactory(factory);
```

**Edit**

head banging after reading Robin's recent answer (+1!) - at last, embarassingly after years and years, I understand what SwingX' DatePickerFormatter is trying to do: that is to support a lookup chain of formatters (from longer to shorter), the longest used after committing, the shorter to ease the typing by users.

Unfortunately that doesn't work as intuitively expected. Given a sequence of formats, longer to shorter (and appropriately configured to the century):

```
"yyyy", "yy"
```

and given input

```
"10"
```

feels like being passed on from first to second, resulting in

```
 2010
```

but isn't. As documented (who reads documention ... lazy me, cough ...) in SimpleDateFormat

> Year: [ ... ] For parsing, if the number of pattern letters is more than 2, the year is interpreted literally, regardless of the number of digits. So using the pattern "MM/dd/yyyy", "01/11/12" parses to Jan 11, 12 A.D.

At the end of the day - as DatePickerFormatter tries to support that lookup but isn't successful - this might be considered a SwingX problem, after all :-)

Comment: kleopatra! I hoped with putting a swingx tag in it, I would gain your attention :D. First of all thank you for your answer and sorry that I wasnt able to comment it already earlier. Unfortunatly I already tried it the way you suggested as well. I know this works perfectly fine. Only thing about it that I dont like is the following: When the user clicks on the textfield while it displayed 27.01.2012, it changes in editmode (because of editformat) to 27.01.12, before the user started changing the date on his own. I would prefer that it still shows 27.01.2012, while he is editing it.

Comment: do you may have any simple suggestion how to achieve this, or do I really have to overwrite the involved JFormattedTextFields to format those strings on my own? I also noticed I can add several formats as editformat. But unfortunatly that didnt help either.

Comment: as already noted in my answer: that's core behaviour, well outside the control of SwingX. Didn't really dig, but I think you generally can't have both - how should the formatter know which to use? You _might_ try to implement a formatter on top of two formats .. please let us know when you succeed, might be a nice contribution to SwingX :-)

Comment: That`s an interesting idea. Since I am running out of time, I'll go with the default behaviour first, but your idea is noted and I'll let you know, as soon as I have a satisfying solution :-)

Comment: @kleopatra take a look at my answer for that composite formatter.

Comment: Good final edit. Concerning your API question/remark ... I think a decent 'Composite format' implementation with predictable/documented logic has more use-cases then adjusting the `DatePickerFormatter` class, and should cover this particular use-case as well

Answer (score 2):

I am not quite aware of JXDatePicker specifically, but if the concrete functionality you want to simulate is: Both user inputs 27.01.2010 and 27.01.10 independently should result in 27.01.2010

**Then this will work:**

```
import java.text.DateFormat;
import java.text.ParseException;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Date;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws ParseException {
        String inputLiteralDateYY = "27.01.10"; //Also works with "27.01.97"
        String inputLiteralDateYYYY = "27.01.2010"; //Also works with "27.01.1997"

        DateFormat dfYYYY = new SimpleDateFormat("dd.MM.yyyy");
        DateFormat dfYY = new SimpleDateFormat("dd.MM.yy");


        Date dateFromYY = dfYY.parse(inputLiteralDateYY);
        Date dateFromYYYY = dfYY.parse(inputLiteralDateYYYY);

        String outputLiteralDateFromYY = dfYYYY.format(dateFromYY);
        String outputLiteralDateFromYYYY = dfYYYY.format(dateFromYYYY);

        System.out.println(outputLiteralDateFromYY);
        System.out.println(outputLiteralDateFromYYYY);
    }
}
```

**The thing is** that first you parse input with "dd.MM.yy" pattern and then return it formatting with "dd.MM.yyyy" pattern.

Hope this helps or helps applying this to your scenario.

Comment: sorry for my late reply, but I am not sure, if I can or should get in between the components validation/formatting process, eventhough I also already considered to overwrite commitEdit of JFormattedTextField to differ on my own, which format is appropiate to use. So I keep this as very last solution in mind. Thank you :)

Answer (score 1):

kleopatra already explained on how to set a `Format` on the date picker. For this use-case, I would apply a combination of a `CompositeFormat` and `ParseAllFormat` instead of having a separate format for editing and regular mode to avoid changing the `String` when you start editing (as you already noticed).

**Composite format**

The composite format, as the name suggests, is a [composite implementation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Composite_pattern) of the `Format` class but only for the parsing. For the formatting, it uses one `Format`. This allows the user to input his/her date in many forms, while it is formatted consistently by using one specific format to format.

You can obtain this behavior as well by writing one more sophisticated `Format`. But in this case, it is easier to just use the formatting/parsing functionality offered by the `SimpleDateFormat` class of the JDK.

```
import java.text.FieldPosition;
import java.text.Format;
import java.text.ParsePosition;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

/**
 * <p>Composite form of {@link java.text.Format Format}. It uses multiple formats for parsing, and
 * only one format for formatting.</p>
 *
 * <p>A possible use-case is the formatting of user input (e.g. in a {@code JFormattedTextField}).
 * Multiple formats for parsing allows accepting multiple forms of user input without having to
 * write a complicated format.</p>
 */
public class CompositeFormat extends Format {

  private List<Format> fFormats = new ArrayList<>();
  private Format fFormattingFormat;

  /**
   * Create a new
   */
  public CompositeFormat() {
  }

  /**
   * Add a format to this composite format
   *
   * @param aFormat The format to add
   */
  public void addFormat( Format aFormat ) {
    assertNotNull( aFormat, "You cannot add a null Format" );
    if ( !( fFormats.contains( aFormat ) ) ) {
      fFormats.add( aFormat );
    }
  }

  /**
   * Remove a format from this composite format
   *
   * @param aFormat The format to remove
   */
  public void removeFormat( Format aFormat ) {
    assertNotNull( aFormat, "You cannot remove a null Format" );
    fFormats.remove( aFormat );
    updateFormattingFormat();
  }

  /**
   * Sets <code>aFormat</code> as the format which will be used for formatting the
   * objects. The format will also be added to the list of available formats.
   * @param aFormat The format which will be used for formatting
   */
  public void setFormattingFormat( Format aFormat ){
    assertNotNull( aFormat, "Formatting format may not be null" );
    addFormat( aFormat );
    fFormattingFormat = aFormat;
  }

  private void assertNotNull( Object aObjectToCheck, String aMessage ) {
    if ( aObjectToCheck == null ) {
      throw new NullPointerException( aMessage );
    }
  }

  private void updateFormattingFormat(){
    if ( !( fFormats.contains( fFormattingFormat ) ) ){
      fFormattingFormat = null;
      if ( !( fFormats.isEmpty() ) ){
        fFormattingFormat = fFormats.iterator().next();
      }
    }
  }

  @Override
  public StringBuffer format( Object obj, StringBuffer toAppendTo, FieldPosition pos ) {
    assertNotNull( fFormattingFormat, "Set a formatting format before using this format" );
    return fFormattingFormat.format( obj, toAppendTo, pos );
  }

  @Override
  public Object parseObject( String source, ParsePosition pos ) {
    if ( fFormats.isEmpty() ){
      throw new UnsupportedOperationException( "Add at least one format before using this composite format" );
    }
    Format formatToUse = fFormats.iterator().next();
    int maxIndex = pos.getIndex();
    for ( Format format : fFormats ) {
      ParsePosition tempPos = new ParsePosition( pos.getIndex() );
      tempPos.setErrorIndex( pos.getErrorIndex() );
      format.parseObject( source, tempPos );
      if ( tempPos.getIndex() > maxIndex ){
        maxIndex = tempPos.getIndex();
        formatToUse = format;
        if( maxIndex == source.length() ){
          //found a format which parses the whole string
          break;
        }
      }
    }
    return formatToUse.parseObject( source, pos );
  }
}
```

**ParseAllFormat**

Typically for user input you want that the whole user input can be formatted/parsed to avoid that the user can input a String which is half-correct. The `ParseAllFormat` is a [decorator](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Decorator_pattern) for a regular `Format` which throws `ParseException`s when only part of the `String` can be parsed.

```
import java.text.AttributedCharacterIterator;
import java.text.FieldPosition;
import java.text.Format;
import java.text.ParseException;
import java.text.ParsePosition;

/**
 * <p>Decorator for a {@link Format Format} which only accepts values which can be completely parsed
 * by the delegate format. If the value can only be partially parsed, the decorator will refuse to
 * parse the value.</p>
 */
public class ParseAllFormat extends Format {
  private final Format fDelegate;

  /**
   * Decorate <code>aDelegate</code> to make sure if parser everything or nothing
   *
   * @param aDelegate The delegate format
   */
  public ParseAllFormat( Format aDelegate ) {
    fDelegate = aDelegate;
  }

  @Override
  public StringBuffer format( Object obj, StringBuffer toAppendTo, FieldPosition pos ) {
    return fDelegate.format( obj, toAppendTo, pos );
  }

  @Override
  public AttributedCharacterIterator formatToCharacterIterator( Object obj ) {
    return fDelegate.formatToCharacterIterator( obj );
  }

  @Override
  public Object parseObject( String source, ParsePosition pos ) {
    int initialIndex = pos.getIndex();
    Object result = fDelegate.parseObject( source, pos );
    if ( result != null && pos.getIndex() < source.length() ) {
      int errorIndex = pos.getIndex();
      pos.setIndex( initialIndex );
      pos.setErrorIndex( errorIndex );
      return null;
    }
    return result;
  }

  @Override
  public Object parseObject( String source ) throws ParseException {
    //no need to delegate the call, super will call the parseObject( source, pos ) method
    return super.parseObject( source );
  }
}
```

The combination of these both classes allows for the following code

```
import java.text.Format;
import java.text.ParseException;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;

public class FormattingDemo {

  private static Format createCompositeDateFormat(){
    Format formattingFormat = new ParseAllFormat( new SimpleDateFormat( "dd.MM.yyyy" ) );
    SimpleDateFormat shortFormat = new SimpleDateFormat( "dd.MM.yy" );
    Format otherFormat = new ParseAllFormat( shortFormat );

    CompositeFormat compositeFormat = new CompositeFormat();
    compositeFormat.addFormat( otherFormat );
    compositeFormat.addFormat( formattingFormat );
    compositeFormat.setFormattingFormat( formattingFormat );
    return compositeFormat;
  }

  public static void main( String[] args ) throws ParseException {
    Format dateFormat = createCompositeDateFormat();
    System.out.println( dateFormat.parseObject( "27.01.2010" ) );
    System.out.println( dateFormat.parseObject( "27.01.10" ) );
    System.out.println( dateFormat.parseObject( "27.01.2012" ) );
    System.out.println(dateFormat.format( dateFormat.parseObject( "27.01.2010" ) ));
    System.out.println(dateFormat.format( dateFormat.parseObject( "27.01.10" ) ));
    System.out.println(dateFormat.format( dateFormat.parseObject( "27.01.2012" ) ));
  }
}
```

resulting in the following output

```
Wed Jan 27 00:00:00 CET 2010
Wed Jan 27 00:00:00 CET 2010
Fri Jan 27 00:00:00 CET 2012
27.01.2010
27.01.2010
27.01.2012
```

Note that there is a small catch for which I did not found a decent solution. The order in which you add `Format` instances to the `CompositeFormat` is also the order in which they are evaluated for the parsing. In this case you need to add them in the correct order as even the `new SimpleDateFormat( "dd.MM.yyyy" )` seems to accept the input string `27.01.10` and can parse the whole `String` to a `Date` object equivalent to `27.01.0010`.

Comment: daaarn ... cough .. see my edit (+1! hopefully this helps to get it right in SwingX)

Comment: @kleopatra I had the same issue with the parsing of the years ... the main reason I added the note about the order of the formats in the composite format