# How to use jXDatePicker with maskFormatter?

Tags: java, swing, datepicker, swingx, maskformatter

I would like to use a jxdatepicker with maskFormatter. I tried

```
MaskFormatter maskFormatter = new MaskFormatter ("##/##/####");
JFormattedTextField field=new JFormattedTextField (maskFormatter);
jXDatePicker.setEditor (field);
```

and

```
MaskFormatter maskFormatter = new MaskFormatter ("##/##/####");
maskFormatter.install (jXDatePicker.getEditor ());
```

neither the first nor the second solution worked

PS:
A `JFormattedTextField` work fine with `MaskFormatter`
AND `jXDatePicker` work fine with a simple `JFormattedTextField`

Comment: Can you explain more on what are you expecting, and what is not working

Comment: I want to do the same thing in the date input in this page [link](http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/input/inputMask.xhtml) but in swing with `JXDatePicker`
If I use a `JFormattedTextField` with `MaskFormatter` i got the expected result, but I want to use `JXDatePicker` so the user can select the date withe the mouse or type it withe the keyboard, And as I said in the question the `MaskFormatter` doesn't work with `JXDatePicker`

Answer (score 1):

This is an old question, but seems to be still active, so here is how we implemented the functionality some time ago (`swingx-all-1.6.5-1.jar`):

**1) Create a wrapper class for** `MaskFormatter`

```
public class Wrapper extends MaskFormatter {

private final static String DD_MM_YYY = "dd/MM/yyyy";

public Wrapper(String string) throws ParseException {
    super(string);

}

@Override
public Object stringToValue(String value) throws ParseException {

    SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat(DD_MM_YYY);
    Date parsed = format.parse(value);
    return parsed;

}

public String valueToString(Object value) throws ParseException {
    if (value != null) {
        SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat(DD_MM_YYY);
        String formated = format.format((Date) value);
        return super.valueToString(formated);
    } else {
        return super.valueToString(value);
    }

  }

}
```

**2) Add the wrapped Formatter to the** `JFormattedTextField` **and set it on the** `JXDatePicker`

```
MaskFormatter maskFormatter;
JXDatePicker datePicker = new JXDatePicker();
try {
        maskFormatter = new Wrapper("##/##/####");
        JFormattedTextField field = new JFormattedTextField(maskFormatter);
        datePicker.setEditor(field);
} catch (ParseException e1) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e1.printStackTrace();
}
somePanel.add(datePicker);
```

The wrapper class basically does the formatting, since trying to set a `DateFormat` on the `JXDatePicker` led to various `ParseException`.

Answer (score 0):

Personally I'm not very skilled in Java but after checking some docs quickly. I think `setEditor` is not the way to go. With `maskFormatter.install` you seem to go into the right direction. Something like this might help you out:

```
JXDatePicker picker = new JXDatePicker();
SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy");
picker.setFormats(format);
```

Selective source: [JXDatePicker using SimpleDateFormat to format dd.MM.yy to dd.MM.yyyy with current century](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9034766/jxdatepicker-using-simpledateformat-to-format-dd-mm-yy-to-dd-mm-yyyy-with-curren?rq=1)

Or check out this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/9036979/4820655

Comment: Nop that will only format the date that way, but the user still has to type the `/` character, what i want is somthing like the date input in this page [link](http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/input/inputMask.xhtml)

Comment: @Billydan so what about the `DatePickerFormatter formatter = new DatePickerFormatter(` code from http://stackoverflow.com/a/9036979/4820655 ?

Comment: Maybe @kleopatra is able to help you with this one.